# How set query parameters in Java Hibernate in OneToMany mapping?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, orm

I have a problem:
I have 3 classes and 3 tables:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "VehiclesBodies")
public class VehicleBody {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "vehicleBodyId")
    private Long vehicleBodyId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "trunk")
    private int trunk;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleModelId")
    private VehicleModel vehicleModel;

    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vehicleBody")
    private List<VehicleDrive> vehicleDrives = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "VehiclesDrives")
public class VehicleDrive {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "vehicleDriveId")
    private Long vehicleDriveId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "engine")
    private double engine;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vehicleBodyId")
    private VehicleBody vehicleBody;

    @ManyToOne//(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dictionaryCarDriveId")
    private DictionaryCarDrive dictionaryCarDrive;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "DictionaryCarDrives")
public class DictionaryCarDrive {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dictionaryCarDriveId")
    private Long dictionaryCarDriveId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dictionaryCarDrive")
    private List<VehicleDrive> vehicleDrives = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I would like to take from the database only models that have a diesel engine and that each of these models in the vehicleDrives list had only disel engines.

```
List<VehicleBody> vehicleBodies = em.createQuery(
        "Select distinct b from VehicleBody b " +
        "join b.vehicleDrives d " +
        "join d.dictionaryCarDrive c " +
        "where c.name=:name ", VehicleBody.class).
    setParameter("name", "Diesel").
    getResultList();
```

Currently, the list includes models that have Diesel engines but contain not only these engines (there are also gasoline engines). I want to have Diesel engines in the vehicleDrives list. I combined with join fetch but nothing helped. I use postgres.

Comment: Why are `VehicleBody.trunk`, `VehicleDrive.drive`, `DictionaryCarDrive.dictionaryCarDriveId` and `DictionaryCarDrive.name` annotated with `@JoinColumn` and not `@Column`? I haven't investigated any further (yet) but that seems odd to me.